# Spark Cassandra Write UDT With Case-Sensitive Names Fails

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

- Spark connector Write fails with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: udtId is not a field defined in this definition` error when using case-sensitive field names
- I need the fields in the Cassandra table to maintain case. So i have used
  quotes to create them.

My Cassandra schema

```
CREATE TYPE my_keyspace.my_udt (
  "udtId" text,
  "udtValue" text
);

CREATE TABLE my_keyspace.my_table (
  "id" text PRIMARY KEY,
  "someCol" text,
  "udtCol" list<frozen<my_udt>>
);
```

My Spark DataFrame schema is

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- someCol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- udtCol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- udtId: string (nullable = true)
           |-- udtValue: string (nullable = true)
```

- Are there any other options to get this write to work other than defining my udt with lowercase names? Making them lower case would make me invoke case management code everywhere this is used and i'd like to avoid that ?
- Because i couldn't write successfully, i did try read yet? Is this an issue with reads as well ?

Comment: what is the SCC version?

Comment: I'm using Connector 2.4.2. JDK 11 and Scala 2.12

Comment: forgot to ask - what Spark version? looking to Scala 2.12, I suspect that it's Spark 3.0?

Comment: No Problem. I should've mentioned as well. I'm using Spark 2.4.5. FYI, i tried adding quotes to the udt fields in the dataframe and that did not help either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0 - I can't find specific commit that fixes it, or specific Jira that mentions that - I suspect that it was fixed in the DataStax version first, and then released as part of merge announced [here](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all).

Here is how it works in SCC 2.5.0 + Spark 2.4.6, while it fails with SCC 2.4.2 + Spark 2.4.6:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

scala> val data = spark.read.cassandraFormat("my_table", "test").load()
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, someCol: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val data2 = data.withColumn("id", concat(col("id"), lit("222")))
data2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, someCol: string ... 1 more field]

scala> data2.write.cassandraFormat("my_table", "test").mode("append").save()
```

Comment: This works with 2.5.0. I'll look into upgrading to 2.5.0 connector version.

Comment: until you aren't using some code that depends on the Java driver classes, like, `withClusterDo`, `withSessionDo`, then migration is straightforward. Also, this release brings a lot of optimizations, like, direct join, etc. - read the linked blog post about it